# What about 'localized' questions?

Tags: discussion

Other sites have close reasons such as 'too localized' which basically means that a question is not likely to help many other visitors aside from the OP, and this is also generally used for timebound questions.

For instance, ["What is the best time of day/Band to make a contact with Hawaii from the East Coast?"](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-is-the-best-time-of-day-band-to-make-a-contact-with-hawaii-from-the-east-co)

I think it's a good question, but the information will be out of date soon. Granted, the question can become the 'goto' for all similar questions in the future (which would be closed as duplicates since this question answers the broader question - how do I determine the best time of day and frequency for communicating between point A and point B?), but we may want to modify the existing question to make that clear if so.

If we want to allow these then that is alright, so long as we're OK with the precedent this sets for hundreds if not thousands more of these questions which will be answered by referring back to the same resources (VOACAP, ARRL propogation forecasts, etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may want to gently guide people towards asking more general questions - e.g. "how can I determine the best time for long range contacts?" instead of the aforementioned example.

We can also encourage more general answers to specific questions, in hopes that they'll provide a better "dupeable" Q&A. I mentioned that in my comment on the accepted answer for that question as well.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was going to say - if you manage to ground the question and reel it in a bit with an answer, they're generally very useful questions to have around. "It probably makes more sense to show you how to figure this out for yourself" will work in _quite_ a few cases.