# Should [propagation] and [range] be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

**Is there a *useful* difference between the tags [propagation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propagation) and [range](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/range)?** It seems to me that “range” is a sub-topic of “propagation”, and one which is not sufficiently specifically-of-interest to be worth tagging (in fact, it's [*somewhat* characteristic of bad questions](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169/proposed-close-reason-impossible-hf-propagation-questions)).

If not, I propose to remove [range](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/range) or make it a synonym of [propagation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propagation).

Answer (score 1):

I think it should probably be made a synonym of the [propagation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propagation) tag.

The [range](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/range) one can communicate with is very different from the [propagation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propagation) that makes the communication possible and thus the [range](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/range) tag should not be deleted but only synonymized.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by your second paragraph? It sounds like an argument against synonymhood.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think this should be done. Propogation seems to refer mostly to DX type contacts, while Range could also refer to point-to-point. In fact, most tags with [range](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/range) refer to point-to-point range, and I think they deserve different tags.

Comment: I agree with you that there tends to be this distinction, but I don't think these are the proper names for it. Is someone going to be interested in one and not the other? Likely yes. But in that case, wouldn't it make more sense to tag with [dx] versus — well, I'm not sure what the other tag would be named, which is a point against this position — than to conflate the "type of operation in question" (dx, local-mobile-repeaters, ...) with "aspect of radio I'm asking about" (propagation, antenna choice, modes, ...) axes of the question?

Comment: I'll give you that, it seems like a better choice of names would be better suited for both. Hmmm... Let me think on that one some.

Comment: Done thinking? :)

Comment: I also agree that we should keep these as separate tags, But largely because most people who ask about 'range' will be relative newbies. For this reason alone we should probably keep that tag as a newbie-indicator (no experienced ham would ask about 'range', rather they would favour terms such as 'propagation' or even 'antenna gain').